# How to find data containing square brackets in microsoft access?

Tags: ms-access, square-bracket

I have a database containing data like [1][24], [2], [45], [36][23][14]. The numbers in square brackets have 2 digits at most. I have trouble with square brackets. For example when I write the query using LIKE and search for '?3?' I want it to find data containing [3]. However it omits the square brackets and returns [36][23][14] since it contains '23]1'. I also tried queries like "["&'3'&"]" and '*[[3]]*' but it didn't work.

Comment: So, the value you're searching for is *JUST* `[3]`?

Comment: The value inside the square brackets can be anything but I want it not to ignore the brackets.

Comment: See if this helps you: `SELECT YourField, InStr(1, [YourField], "[3]") AS Test
FROM YourTable`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the first square bracket, it is a special character:

```
 WHERE SomeText Like "*[[]3]*"
```

Even though the second square bracket is also a special character, it does not need to be escaped.

If you simply want any single number in square brackets contained in a field / column:

```
 WHERE SomeText Like "*[[]#]*"
```